# Dynamic social media component w/ dark mode

Tags: react.js, jsx

**Note: This is my first post for a code review, so any feedback on what other info would be helpful to post (if any) would be much appreciated!**

React component: Social.js

The component has an input of 4 properties:

- dark: Boolean - if dark is supplied, the component renders white icons for contrast against a dark background
- facebook: String - if facebook url is supplied, the component renders the facebook icon, else no icon at all
- twitter: String - if twitter url is supplied, the component renders the twitter icon, else no icon at all
- instagram: String - if instagram url is supplied, the component renders the instagram icon, else no icon at all

**If only 1 social media url is supplied, the text "*Follow us on:* " is rendered along with the single icon**

```
let count = 0;

function countProp (prop) {
  if (prop !== undefined) {
    if (prop.url !== ``) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return prop;
}

const Social = props => {
  count = 0;
  let facebook = countProp(props.facebook);
  let twitter = countProp(props.twitter);
  let instagram = countProp(props.instagram);
  return (
    <>
    <div className="social">
      { (count == 1) ? <span>Follow us on:</span> : `` }
      
      { (!props.dark) ?
                ( (facebook.url !== ``) ? 
                  <a href={facebook.url}>
                      <img src="./assets/social/facebook.svg" alt="facebook"></img>
                  </a> 
                  : null )
                : ( (facebook.url !== ``) ? 
                  <a href={facebook.url}>
                      <img src="./assets/social/facebook_white.svg" alt="facebook"></img>
                  </a> 
                  : null ) }

      { (!props.dark) ?
                ( (twitter.url !== ``) ? 
                  <a href={twitter.url}>
                      <img src="./assets/social/twitter.svg" alt="twitter"></img>
                  </a> 
                  : null )
                : ( (twitter.url !== ``) ? 
                  <a href={twitter.url}>
                      <img src="./assets/social/twitter_white.svg" alt="twitter"></img>
                  </a> 
                  : null ) }

      { (!props.dark) ?
                ( (instagram.url !== ``) ? 
                  <a href={instagram.url}>
                      <img src="./assets/social/instagram.svg" alt="instagram"></img>
                  </a> 
                  : null )
                : ( (instagram.url !== ``) ? 
                  <a href={instagram.url}>
                      <img src="./assets/social/instagram_white.svg" alt="instagram"></img>
                  </a> 
                  : null ) }

    </div>

    <style type="text/css"> {
          `
      .social {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .social img {
        max-height: 25px;
        margin: 0 15px;
      }

    `
    }
    </style>
    </>
    
)};

export default Social;
```

Answer (score 1):

- consider using The strict equality operator (===) over the abstract equality operator (==) , see [== VS ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)
- avoid nested `if` blocks using `optional chaining` , it can get pretty messy if you have a lot of nested properties, it's a relatively new feature but you can always use [a babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining).
- consider a different aproach to styling ( i recommend [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) ), adding styles like that would affect other components on the same page.
- since the images urls' are hardcoded , use an object to toggle `dark mode`
- keep your code [DRY](https://medium.com/jl-codes/dry-vs-wet-code-589c564aa5aa) , you can use an Array of social media names and loop through it to display the icons
- for counting the `props` , you could use `Object.keys` or if you have other props to pass along the social media icons, use `Array.filter` to check how many are there and grab the resulting array's `length`

snippet of the end result :

```
import styeld from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  .social {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .social img {
    max-height: 25px;
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
`;

const icons = {
  darkMode: {
    facebook: "facebook_white",
    twitter: "twitter_white",
    instagram: "instagram_white"
  },

  lightMode: {
    facebook: "facebook",
    twitter: "twitter",
    instagram: "instagram"
  }
}

const options = ["facebook", "twitter", "imstagram"];

const Social = props => {
  // check for dark mode
  const mode = props.dark ? "darkMode" : "lightMode";

  // count social media icons 
  const count = option.filter(option => props[option]?.url ? true : false).length();

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="social">
        {/* show the text if there's at least one social media is supplied */}
        {count > 1 ? <span>Follow us on:</span> : ``}

        {
          // loop through the social media array to display the ones available in props
          options.map(option => props[option]?.url 
            ? <a href={props[option]?.url}>
               <img src={`./assets/social/${icons[mode].facebook}.svg`} alt={option} /> 
              </a> 
           : null)
        }

      </div>
    </Wrapper>

  )
};

export default Social;
```